# When do I make an API call

Tags: swift, api, architecture, clean-architecture

I am currently using VIP architecture and I was wondering when I should make an API call.

For example, I have two views. A connection view leading to a list view.
The list needs the user to connect to load.

My question is, where should I make my API call to fetch data for the second view ?

- Should I make the request as soon as the connection succeeds, and then launch the 2nd view once I get the data of this request.

Or

- Should I launch the 2nd view first and then make the request for this view ?

The first solution seems slightly faster, but the second one feels cleaner.
What do you think ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, VIP/MVC/MVVM architecture has nothing to do with your issue, none of there architectures has rules about when you need to make API calls.

Everything depends on your needs and tech requirements.

As for me there is two most important points:

- if your second screen is data sensitive and you need to be sure, that it display latest data - make API call after this screen was displayed and update it UI with latest data.
- if you don't care if data that you display is latest/ or you this data would not be updated very often/ or you show static data that would be rarely changed, BUT for you is important that user will see next screen immediately - make API call as soon as it possible(preferably on app launch)

If both previous points is not important for you - make API call after screen will be displayed. It will guaranty that you has latest data.

But you need to remember that `there is no rule about it`, so make API calls when you really need it.